# SQL Server avoiding Cursors

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I am just reading about SQL Server cursors, that I should avoid them as much as I can :)

Is there ALWAYS a way to write a query/function/procedure without cursors?

I have found some examples on the Net, but they are usually rather simple.

My example - can I avoid cursors?:

Let's have an update procedure X taking an account id and a transaction id - this is the unique key of the row I want to update

But there are more transactions for an account

```
SELECT accID, transID from table
```

Now I use a cursor to loop on the table, always taking the `accID` and `transID` to get the row and update it

Can I do it a non-cursor way?

Thanks

Comment: How are you updating - what's the logic? It completely depends on the logic, but for most operations, yes, you can?

Comment: I have an accountID, but in 'table' there are 'sub-account numbers' = I have ACC111, but there is ACC111-001; ACC111-002. That means i get all transactionID:subAccountNum pairs for One accountID and then use a Cursor to loop over this pairs and UPDATE table SET x=y WHERE subAccId=@subAccId and transID=@transID (does this help?)

Comment: Check this link, there are lot of nice examples: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

Comment: Cursors are not arbitrarily bad. If it were, they would be deprecated by now, don't you think? There are places where the use of cursors would be ideal. Sadly, these are few and far apart. Use Cursors, but with extreme caution.

Comment: There are, off-course, situations where cursors are OK and meant to be used. Looping through table to update specific rows is absolutely not one of them. If you have problem replacing your cursor with set based operation, please post your whole query and I am sure you can get help here.

Comment: @Raj Of course, I dont believe Cursors are arbitrarily bad, but from what I have read, they usually are and I try to figure out when I can use them and when it is better to replace them and How?

Comment: @Nenad Thanks for the link, it helped. I have posted most of the query (at least the base, since I can not copy it whole) as a new Answer bellow.

Answer (score 1):

I was asked for more info about what I want to do, it is a bit too long, so I will add it here as a new comment.. I can not copy the code here, so I am trying to capture at least the base.

My code looked like:

```
DECLARE @headAcc varchar(20)
set @headAcc='ACC111'

declare @id varchar(20), @clId varchar(20)
declare cur CURSOR for
select addID, transID from Table1
where accID like @headAcc+'%' and...
order by 1 desc

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT from cur into @accID, @transID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
 -- 1
 update Table2
  set colX = ...
 where accID=@accID and transID=@transID and...
 -- 2
 update Table3
  set colY = ...
 where accID=@accID and transID=@transID and...

 FETCH NEXT from cur into @accID, @transID
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Thanks for the help in answers and link in comments, I was not very familiar with UPDATE JOINs, and that should be the answer.

After reading the articles I came up with 2 updates in form like:

```
DECLARE @headACC varchar(20)
set @headACC='ACC111'

update t2
set t2.colX = ... 
from Table2 t2
     join Table1 t1
on t1.accID=t2.accID
 and t1.transID=t2.transID
where t1.accID like @headAcc+'%' 
 and...
```

It seems to work. Any other comments appreciated eg. if there is a more effective way.

Answer (score 0):

See this example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx#OtherTables) on how to update one table based on data in other tables:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
UPDATE Sales.SalesPerson
SET SalesYTD = SalesYTD + SubTotal
FROM Sales.SalesPerson AS sp
JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS so
    ON sp.BusinessEntityID = so.SalesPersonID
    AND so.OrderDate = (SELECT MAX(OrderDate)
                        FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
                        WHERE SalesPersonID = sp.BusinessEntityID);
GO
```